# dynamic html name according to PHP output?

Tags: php, html

I am using a small piece of code to generate a static html page via PHP.

This is the code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
file_put_contents('someName.html', ob_get_contents());
// end buffering and displaying page
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

The code above works fine and it will create the html page (someName.html).

what i am trying to do is to change the name of the html from "someName".html to the PHP output. the PHP page is a dynamic PHP page which will show some results according to users requested stuff via a html form.

For example: the user enter 2 in an input box and the html page that is created will be 2.html instead of someName.php.

I did try something like this but that didn't work:

```
<?php
ob_start();
file_put_contents($usersInput'.html', ob_get_contents());
// end buffering and displaying page
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

does anyone know how I need to do this?

EDIT:

I've tried it this way now:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['userInput']))    
{ 
file_put_contents($_POST['userInput'].'.html', ob_get_contents());

}
// end buffering and displaying page
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

so basically the user enters 2 in the input field in the html form and the html file should be called 2.html.

AND I GET THIS ERROR:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(2.html) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory on line 1156.
```

and this is on line 1156:

```
file_put_contents($_POST['userInput'].'.html', ob_get_contents());
```

Comment: You can use $_GET['page_name'].'.html' All you need is to pass to that peace of code some variable (in your case page name). Tell me if this is working for you?

Comment: @pregmatch, I've tried your suggestion like this: file_put_contents($_POST[$timezone1].'.html', ob_get_contents()); and this only create  a page like this (.html) with no name and only html extension. any ideaS?

Comment: Have you checked what's in `$_GET` and `$_POST`? If you want to output the contents to see, use `var_dump($_GET);` or `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @n00dle, file_put_contents('someName.html', ob_get_contents()); works fine and it will output the content correctly. my question is no t about the content. its about the html name.

Comment: I know, I'm not talking about the content either. You said when you did `$_POST[$timezone1].'.html'`, you only got `.html` as the filename, which implies that there is nothing to read on `$_POST` at the index you're using. What is the value in the variable `$timezone1`? Did you mean to put `$_POST['timezone1']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a syntax error, you forgot a concatination operator:

```
file_put_contents($usersInput'.html', ob_get_contents());

file_put_contents($usersInput.'.html', ob_get_contents());
                             ^ -- here
```

**edit**

For your `failed to open stream` error, you should probably use an absolute path. This is always recommended when working with files.

If you want to place the file in the same directory as where the script is running:

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/'.$_POST['userInput'].'.html', ob_get_contents());
```

also be aware that the user could input a name with characters that would not produce a valid filename!

also, you probably should make sure that the directory is writable:

```
is_writable(__DIR__);
```

check [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) on magic constants such as `__DIR__`

Comment: well, based on the info you provided, there is not much more I can tell you. `file_put_content` should work when given a valid file name, and content...

Comment: Yes, file_put_content works fine as long as i give it a static name like someName.html . but I am trying to generate the html name according to users chosen stuff via the form as i mentioned above.

Comment: well, the function does not know if it received a static name of a dynamic one, it just gets the passed string, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: have you tried starting your script with `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`? or checked the PHP error log?

Comment: okay, i did try the ini_set for error checking and i saw this error on my page: Notice: Undefined index on line 1153 and on that line i've got this: file_put_contents($_POST[$userInput].'.html', ob_get_contents());

Comment: what is the `name` of the user input field in HTML? that should be put inside `$userInput` variable.

Comment: the name of the input field is userInput.

Comment: well, then it should be `file_put_contents($_POST['userInput'].'.html', ob_get_contents());`

Comment: This doesn't create anything at all?!

Comment: sorry but unfortunately this one returns the same error and adds __DIR__/ before the html name. for example it will show: Warning: file_put_contents( __DIR__/2.html) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory on line 1156.